# Caja drag and drop with tree view

Tags: 20.04, mate, drag-and-drop, caja

I just switched to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Mate because Mint MATE was buggy and annoying.

Ubuntu MATE is a great distro but one thing I like better about Mint MATE was in Caja if you drag an item from the main panel into a folder in the tree view panel it would highlight the folder so you knew exactly which folder you were going to drop into.

Caja in Ubuntu Mate doesn't do this.

I have tried a few different themes that come with Ubuntu.

Does anyone have a suggestion to enable this feature?

Thanks in advance

Added a picture from XFCE. Notice the highlight on the "New Folder" in the left panel.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I added a picture from XFCE to show what I am talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Caja has Tree and Places views in the left Side Pane.
In Ubuntu MATE 20.04.3 LTS with default Ambiant and Radiant themes it really does not highlight possible drop location.

So you have two options:

- use Extra Pane with any MATE theme which is opened by <kbd>F3</kbd> and switch one of the panes to List View:

  [image: Extra Pane]
- install modern Yaru theme from [special PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/yaru-mate) and use your original method with Tree or Places view in Side Pane

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/yaru-mate
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

  then choose the Yaru-MATE-Light theme in MATE Control Center → Appearance.

  To get the following functionality for Places

  [image: Yaru Places]

  and for Tree

  [image: Yaru Tree]

Comment: This does achieve the desired effects but I have discovered after using it that it causes Caja to crash.

Comment: Please report bugs to both Launchpad by `apport-bug caja` and https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/issues .